# How to output required cost from switch statement

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. It says that my variables are not defined, but I did that at the top of the js file. I think all my logic is correct, but something is not right somewhere I haven't been able to figure out what it is. I'm just adding more text here so it will let me edit this question with updated coded. Delete this last bit as needed. Thanks.

```
function calculate() {
    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "Cost: "

    var cost = Number(document.getElementById("type").value);
    var years = Number(document.getElementById("years").value);
      if (years > 1) {
        var discount = cost * 0.20
        cost -= discount ; // 20%
        document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML += cost;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML += cost;
      }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `cost` before doing `switch(cost)`. What is it supposed to be comparing its value to?

Comment: the cost outlined in the html type option value.

Comment: What are `type.basic`, `type.premium`, etc.? `type` is a DOM element, it doesn't have those properties. I think what you want to do is `switch(type.value)` and the `case "basic":`, `case "premium":`, etc.

Comment: That should be `var cost = parseInt(document.getElementById("cost").value)`

Comment: `cost * 20` should be `cost * 0.20`

Comment: Like so?         switch (type.value) {
            case "basic":
                ("Basic - $10.00");
                break;
            case "premium":
                ("Premium - $15.00");
                break;
            case "gold":
                ("Gold - $20.00");
                break;
            case "platinum":
                ("Platinum - $25.00");
        }

Comment: `switch (type.value) { case "basic": console.log("Basic - $10.00")...`

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: there is no console though? At least thats the error I get. "console is not defined"

Comment: Maybe that's because of `use strict`. Try `window.console.log`

Comment: Still the same error. "windows is not defined" should I just remove strict? I would update my question but it wont let me.

Answer (score 0):

I made two changes and it runs without error:

```
var cost = parseInt(document.getElementById("cost).value);
```

Should have another " after cost, and:

```
if (type && type.value && years && (years > 0)) {
```

should be years.value > 0

Then change the switch to:

```
switch (type.value) {
```

and the cases to:

```
case 'basic':
case 'premium':
```

etc.

```js
function calculate() {
    // Be strict:
    'use strict';

    // Variable to store the total cost:
    var cost;

    // Get a reference to the form elements:
    var type = document.getElementById('type');
    var years = document.getElementById('years');

    // TODO Convert the year to a number:

    // Check for valid data:
    if (type && type.value && years && (years.value > 0)) {

        // TODO Add a switch statement to determine the base cost using the value of "type"
        switch (type.value) {
            case 'basic':
                window.console.log("Basic - $10.00");
                break;
            case 'premium':
                window.console.log("Premium - $15.00");
                break;
            case 'gold':
                window.console.log("Gold - $20.00");
                break;
            case 'platinum':
                window.console.log("Platinum - $25.00");
        }

        // TODO Update cost to factor in the number of years:
        var cost = parseInt(document.getElementById("cost").value);

        // Discount multiple years:
        if (years > 1) {
            cost -= (cost*20); // 20%
        }

        // TODO update the value property of 'costElement' to the calculated cost
        var costElement = document.getElementById('cost');


    } else { // Show an error:
        document.getElementById('cost').value = 'Please enter valid values.';
    }

    // Return false to prevent submission:
    return false;
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    // call a function named calculate() when form submitted
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = calculate;
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>58123301</title>
<head>
<body>
<div>
<form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
<fieldset><legend>Create Your Membership</legend>
<div><label for="type">Type</label> <select name="type" id="type" required>
   <option value="basic">Basic - $10.00</option>
   <option value="premium">Premium - $15.00</option>
   <option value="gold">Gold - $20.00</option>
   <option value="platinum">Platinum - $25.00</option>
</select></div>
<div><label for="years">Years</label><input type="number" name="years" id="years" min="1" required></div>
        <div><label for="cost">Cost</label><input type="text" name="cost" id="cost" disabled></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="58123301.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could not get your answer working. Do you mind providing a code snippet of it running?

Comment: Yes no problem - I copied your code and made the above changes. "Could not get your answer working" - what happens?

Comment: Ahh I see what it was. I need the cost to be displayed in the disable "cost" input field not the log. Also, it's suppose to be a 20% discount for the selected type if they enter more than one year. Still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your code and I fixed a few issues, hope this will help you:

```js
function calculate() {
        document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "Cost: "

        var cost = Number(document.getElementById("type").value);
        var years = Number(document.getElementById("years").value);
        if (years > 1) {
          var discount = cost * 0.20
          cost -= discount ; // 20%
          document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML += cost;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML += cost;
        }
        return false;
      }
```

```html
    <form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Create Your Membership</legend>
        <div>
          <label for="type">Type</label>
          <select name="type" id="type" required>
            <option value="10.00">Basic - $10.00</option>
            <option value="15.00">Premium - $15.00</option>
            <option value="20.00">Gold - $20.00</option>
            <option value="25.00">Platinum - $25.00</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="years">Years</label
          ><input type="number" name="years" id="years" min="1" required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <p id="cost">Cost: </p>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="calculate" id="submit" onclick="calculate()"/>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: This does not properly input the output into the cost textfield and does not calculate a 20% discount if more than one year.

Comment: @RachelWillows, if you don't mind, can you please describe a clear explanation of your requirements, will be glad to help:)

Comment: What's the purpose of the `years` value?

Comment: @ ShayaUlman "Complete this form to calculate your membership. There's a 20% discount if you enroll for more than one year" The cost must be reflected in the disabled text field on the html page. This help?

Comment: 20% discount of the `Basic - $10.00` as an example? then you have to store the prices in variables

Comment: Yes and display it in the disabled "cost" input field.

Comment: Only a 20% discount if they choose more than one year.

Comment: I'm really struggling with getting it to display into the "cost" input field instead of the log.

Comment: Declare costElement under your cost declaration, then use costElement.value = "Premium - $15.00"; (or whatever you need it to be).

Comment: @RachelWillows, Please check my updated answer, let me know if it helps!

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I'm going to review this and see where my catch up's were.